# SSIS package fails as a SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: ssis

I have a package that imports from a AS400 file to SQL. The package executes properly within Visual Studio, but fails when set up as a scheduled job. the error message is that my password is incorrect. I know that it is correct. I also setup a package configuration and this did not work. I have searched and tried many things. Could someone give me some assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Your password is incorrect.

Seriously, you "know" that your password is correct? You know better than the code attempting to use your password? Does this seem likely to you?

Consider the possibility that you and SSIS may be referring to different passwords. Maybe the one you "know" is correct actually is, but the other one is not.

Comment: Well i know that it successfully connect to the source in the DB connections within the package using visual studio. And the package runs succefully within VS. If the password was not correct, this process wouldn't work, right? if i look at the command line tab in the first step, the password is not in the string. should it be? i see all the other connection information but not this. I tried adding it with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a stupid answer, but how are you connecting to the AS400? If it's using ODBC drivers, you'll need the AS400 drivers installed on both local (dev) and your SQL server box.  They're notoriously picky about versions.

If memory serves me correctly, when you set up the ODBC connection using the AS400 driver software, I think you need to specify connection details as well and they get explicitly saved in the ODBC connection.

Answer (score 0):

The support link above is correct. To boil it down to a simple answer. Password protect your SSIS package to save the credentials needed to connect to the AS400.

Answer (score 0):

With the ODBC configuration: use a system DSN instead of user DSN, it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use odbc connection or try to redeploy the package on your SSIS Server.